# Where can you find the location-id for Instagram's API? Or using LAT LNG?

Tags: geolocation, instagram, instagram-api

Looking through Instagram's API documentation, you can pull photos based on a `location-id`, but as far as I can tell there's no instructions as to where you can find this id.

Here's the relevant page on Instagram: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

If I just the LAT and LNG to get a geographic spot (using Google maps, for example), how precise will the results be? Will there be some fuzziness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lat and lng you can search for locations by geographic coordinate using this endpoint.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=1&lng=2&access_token=Your-Act
You'll get list of places inside the geo cordinate.
Also you  can search place by facebook place id and foursquare id.